# MsgWaitForMultipleObjects returns error for Office 2013 64-bit version

Tags: ms-office, add-in, office-addins, office-2013

My company has an Office Add-in that works on Office 2007 and 2010 without problem. Now Microsoft has a new Office 2013, we need to test the add-in in Office 2013 (32-bit and 64-bit).

Most of the functions are working fine, but somehow there is one function which use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() is not working properly in Office 2013 64-bit version, it works fine on the 32-bit Office 2013.  Below is my code, it is within a function:

```
Dim lReturn As Integer

  Do While True

     'Wait on event
     lReturn = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, handle, 0, timeout, QS_ALLEVENTS)

     Select Case lReturn

        Case -1

           'Call failed
           Err.Raise(vbObjectError, "WaitWithEvents", "MsgWaitForMultipleObjects Failed")

        Case STATUS_TIMEOUT

           'Timed out
           WaitWithEvents = STATUS_TIMEOUT
           Exit Function

        Case 1

           'Event needs to be processed
           Application.DoEvents()

        Case Else

           'Event has been signaled
           WaitWithEvents = 0
           Exit Function

     End Select
  Loop
```

Most of the time MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() will returned -1 the Office application will crash/hang. I am new to MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() and had tried changing the code here and there but still couldn't solve the problem.

Is the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() works well in 64-bit version of Office 2013? Or some modification needs to be done specifically for the 64-bit Office?  Or do I need to register the DLL differently? The add-in project is set to any cpu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem is in the declaration of the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects().
Previously I declared it this way:

```
Private Declare Function MsgWaitForMultipleObjects Lib "user32" (ByVal nCount As Integer, ByRef pHandles As Integer, ByVal fWaitAll As Integer, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Integer, ByVal dwWakeMask As Integer) As Integer
```

The solution is:

```
Private Declare Function MsgWaitForMultipleObjects Lib "user32" (ByVal nCount As Integer, ByRef pHandles As IntPtr, ByVal fWaitAll As Boolean, ByVal dwMilliseconds As UInteger, ByVal dwWakeMask As Integer) As Integer
```